# Capitalize input in a CakePHP Form

Tags: php, html, css, cakephp

I have a form in my website that collects the name of the user among others. Each user is free to introduce any letter as a name and it will be valid. My problem is that I would like all the names to be saved with only the first letter capitalized.

Examples:

Name: `alexander` *(I want to save the string "Alexander")*

Name: `ALEXANDER smith` *(I want to save the string "Alexander Smith")*

I know about the function ucwords() but I haven't managed to use it propperly in my code. Please, find it below.

```
<label for="firstname"><?= __("Name") ?> *</label>
<?= $this->Form->text("firstname"); ?>
```

```
$contact = $this->Contacts->newEntity(); 
$contact->firstname = $data["firstname"];
```

Can I use the ucwords() function somewhere in this code?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/entities.html#accessors-mutators

Answer (score 0):

I believe this solves

```
ucwords($data["firstname"]);
```

Comment: Does this give the output required of`Alexander Smith`

Comment: This would be a good candidate to go into a `beforeMarshal` function.

Comment: If you want to convert ALEXANDER to Alexander, then you'd need not `ucwords($data['firstname'])`, but `ucwords(strtolower($data['firstname']))`. But do beware that this will break things like "O'Reilly" and "MacDonald" and "vanHouten" and "J.R.".

Comment: Thank you all for the details. It works! Thank you :)